# Why isn't my spring boot @RequestMapping working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class DataSetController {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/cars/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String testFetch() {
         return "HELLO";

     }
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface DataSetRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DataSet, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<DataSet> {}
```

The logs at startup indicate the following:

> 2015-08-21 18:49:46.050  INFO 52448 --- [           main]
>   o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped
>   "{[/cars/test],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String
>   com.example.hello.dataset.DataSetController.testFetch()

My base uri in my config is:

base-uri:  /api

So I should be able to get localhost:8080/api/cars/test

But here is what I get in the logs:

> 2015-08-21 18:58:10.847  WARN 52476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP
>   request with URI [/api/cars/test] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'dispatcherServlet'

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your base URI `/api` is not set properly in your configuration, that's why the dispatcher can't find a proper mapping.

Since all your requests will have the `/api` base I suggest you add a @RequestMapping annotation to your Controller :

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DataSetController {

}
```

Comment: This is correct, and it fixed my issue, but any idea why would my other controllers work as expected? I have an application configuration in which I have spring.data.rest.base-uri=/api It's just this controller that isn't working as expected

Comment: Glad I helped. Apparently there is an ongoing issue with spring.data.rest.* configuration (see [bug report](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2392)). Did you extend the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` ?

Answer (score 0):

You've said that you've used `base-uri` in your config, but it should be `spring.data.rest.base-uri`.